# How to Import a Picture in Flash from Photoshop Without the change in quality

Tags: flash, photoshop, resolution, image

I try to import a PNG image from photoshop to flash. But in flash i only get image of lower quality. The image is so blur. Its frustrating for me. Kindly Give me Solution for this

Comment: Are you altering the dimensions of the image from their original? That could cause what you're referring to.

Comment: Yes, We attempting to reduce the size of the image.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by ruyadorno, I would _not_ alter the image dimensions after importing. Instead, create the image in Photoshop at whatever size(s) you need, then import those sizes. Any time you scale the image, you run the risk of it being altered in some way, such as making it blurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flash extra-compact your image when you import it, it's an option by default in the program. To change it just go to the library, right-click on your image, choose properties and in the new window just change the "Compression" combo-box to Lossless (PNG/GIF).
It should let your image untouched.